# Python Selenium First Project - loop through pages and check/uncheck tick boxes

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

New to Python/Selenium and learning on the fly with my first basic selenium script.

Request user input - activate or deactivate.
Open's website, loops through shop URL as well as activate/deactivate checkboxes.

Would be grateful for some feedback on how to optimise the code.

```
# IMPORTS
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# X PATH LOCATIONS
shop = '//*[@id="zz2_TopNavigationMenun1"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a'
product_range = '//*[@id="zz1_QuickLaunchMenun2"]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/a'
product_sale = '//*[@id="divBdyGroup_WG_Main"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a'
product_record = '//*[@id="Enregistrer_HolWebArticlesCaisse_ctl00_m_g_a26e7d54_b496_4e0f_8176_7ddab403a0c0"]'
# WEB MAG URL
webmag_login = 'URL'
webmag_url = 'URL'
# CONTROLS
shopcodes = ['251' ,'257' ,'268' ,'271' ,'285' ,'411' ,'495' ,'787' ,'794' ,'838' ,'842' ,'847' ,'852' ,'857' ,'977' ,'978' ,'979' ,'A74' ,'A75' ,'A77' ,'A78' ,'B08' ,'C01' ,'C02' ,'D14' ,'D93' ,'E41' ,'E42' ,'E50' ,'G38' ,'G52' ,'G84' ,'G85' ,'G95' ,'R20' ,'R67']  # SHOP CODES TO CHECK
plucodes = ["2432"]  # PLU CODES TO CHECK
# VARIABLES
prompt = input("Do you want to \'activate\' or \'deactivate\' items?\n\n")
# OPTIONS
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

##################################################

print("\n[ --------------- ACTIVE PRODUCT CHECK ------------]\n\nShop codes to check :")
print(shopcodes)
print("\nPLU codes to check :")
print(plucodes)
print("\n[ ------------- STARTING MAIN SCRIPT --------------]\n")


##################################################

def webmag_launch_login():
    print(">>> launch web driver")
    driver.get(webmag_login)
    # driver.fullscreen_window()
    print(">>> open and login to webmag\n\n[ ------------ ITERATE THROUGH SHOPS --------------]\n")
    time.sleep(1)


def webmag_nav_to_range_tick():
    for Y in shopcodes:
        driver.get(webmag_url + Y)
        print(Y + " - Login to Store")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_range).click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_sale).click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("[ - CHECKING ITEMS -- ]")

        for X in plucodes:  # iterate through PLU CODES
            try:
                checkbox = "//td[div=\'" + X + "\']/following-sibling::td/input[@type=\'checkbox\']"
                productname = "//td[div=\'" + X + "\']/following-sibling::td[1]"
                result = driver.find_element_by_xpath(checkbox).is_selected()
                if result:
                    print(X + " - " + driver.find_element_by_xpath(productname).text + "\tPLU - already ticked")
                    # print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(productname).text)
                else:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(checkbox).click()
                    print(X + " - " + driver.find_element_by_xpath(productname).text + "\tPLU - ticked")
                time.sleep(1)

            except:
                print(X + "- PLU - not found")
                time.sleep(1)
            # driver.find_element_by_xpath(shop).click()

        # SAVE BUTTON
        # driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_record).click()


def webmag_nav_to_range_untick():
    for Y in shopcodes:
        driver.get(webmag_url + Y)
        print(Y + " - Login to Store")
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_range).click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_sale).click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print("[ - CHECKING ITEMS -- ]")

        for X in plucodes:  # iterate through PLU CODES
            try:
                checkbox = "//td[div=\'" + X + "\']/following-sibling::td/input[@type=\'checkbox\']"
                productname = "//td[div=\'" + X + "\']/following-sibling::td[1]"
                result = driver.find_element_by_xpath(checkbox).is_selected()
                if result:
                    print(X + " - " + driver.find_element_by_xpath(productname).text + "\tPLU - unticked")
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(checkbox).click()
                else:
                    print(X + " - " + driver.find_element_by_xpath(productname).text + "\tPLU - already unticked")
                time.sleep(1)

            except:
                print(X + "- PLU - not found")
                time.sleep(1)
            # driver.find_element_by_xpath(shop).click()

        # SAVE BUTTON
        # driver.find_element_by_xpath(product_record).click()


# EXECUTE DEF

if prompt == "activate":
    webmag_launch_login()
    webmag_nav_to_range_untick()
elif prompt == "deactivate":
    webmag_launch_login()
    webmag_nav_to_range_tick()
else:
    print("Script Ended")
print("Script Finished Running")
```

Comment: It's fine to obscure your credentials, but please don't obscure the original `webmag_url`. Reviewers being able to access the site will be able to more meaningfully comment on the best way to interact with it.

Comment: Unfortunately the URL is not accessible outside the organisation network.

Comment: In that case could you [edit] your post to include a sample of the HTML that is being returned by the URL?

Comment: Appreciate where you guys are coming from.  This platform and the eqtiquette is all new to me.  Programming - HTML / Python is not my background.  I literally studied "Automate Boring Stuff" earlier this week and managed to write this script.  I'll need to figure out how to extract the website and upload it somewhere for users.

Comment: You don't appear to actually authenticate to the website, which points toward using Requests instead of Selenium.

Comment: The authentication for the website is in the form of a popup (Java?).  Initially I tried to us the geckodriver and switch_to.alert(), but I couldn't get it to work after spending hours on it.  I eventually switched to the Chrome driver and found that this method works : 

`driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/")`